# MVC Ajax form won't submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

In my MVC 4 application, I have an Ajax form for search in the master/layout view and an Add form view using the same layout view. On this page, which is containing two forms, Ajax form won't work or won't submit where as the Add will submit.

Ajax form is created using a partial view and it does work on all the pages where we don't have other forms. Any ideas to how to get this work? thanks

Controller Action

```
 public ActionResult SearchResults(SearchFormViewModel filterModel, string searchTerm = "")
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterModel.SearchTerm) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            filterModel.SearchTerm = searchTerm;
        }

        var filter = DataMarketFilter.NewInstance();
        filter.SearchTerm = filterModel.SearchTerm;
        filter.Theme = filterModel.Themes;
        filter.Publisher = filterModel.Publishers;
        filter.Coverage = filterModel.Coverage;
        filter.Year = filterModel.Year;
        filter.SortBy = filterModel.SortBy;

        SearchResultsModel model = this.UnitOfWork.DatasetRepository.SearchProfiles(filter);
        return this.View(model);
    }
```

Search form partial view

```
@model SFRS.DataMarketPlace.Web.Models.SearchFormViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchResults", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" }, new   { @id = "FilterForm", @role = "form" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Form submission was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="input-group stylish-input-group col-md-12 pull-left">
    <label class="sr-only" for="Search Term">Search Term</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchTerm, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "64", placeholder = "Search For Datasets ..." })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SearchTerm)
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <button type="submit" name="Send" value="Search">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
<br />

}
```

Add View

```
@using SFRS.DataMarketPlace.Web.Models
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers
@model SFRS.DataMarketPlace.Web.Models.DatasetViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Add";
Layout = "_Layout_noBanner.cshtml";
}
<div class="container">

<div class="well">
    <h4 class="strong">Add New Dataset</h4>
    <p>
        Please complete as much as you know, and we will fill in the rest. Fields marked with red asterisk <font color="red">*</font>are mandatory.
    </p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-8 well">

    @using (@Html.BeginForm("Save", "Dataset", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "DocumentForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
             // some fields      

            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        @* <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>*@Save
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

    }
```

Comment: any errors in console? and second question. Do You have `jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax` in your project? If I'm not wrong this isn't by default

Comment: No errors in console and yes I do have Jquery Unobtrusive Ajax on the page

Comment: How does your Controller Action look like?

Comment: I have added the controller action code

Comment: can we see the views code?

Comment: for me problem could be here: `public ActionResult SearchResults(SearchFormViewModel filterModel, string searchTerm = "")` You have only one field in form 'searchTerm' and i believe that its the only thing send to the controller. But controller method is waiting for 2 parameters. Please comment `SearchFormViewModel filterModel` and check if now it enters the method

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

**View:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Test", "YOURCONTROLLERNAME", new { searchTerm = "" }, null))
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchResults(SearchFormViewModel filterModel, string searchTerm)
```

Also try this:

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YOURCONTROLLERNAME", "SearchResults"))
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchResults(SearchFormViewModel filterModel)
```

If this doesn't work let me know.